# While inside for loop produces infinite loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I apologize for being a newbie, but why does this loop run forever?

```
for i in range (1,3):
    while i < 5:
        print ('ha')
```

Comment: Where does `i` get updated? Also, there might be some scoping issues with `i`.  It's never a good idea to reuse variable names inside scopes.

Comment: A different way to phrase your question: why would this loop stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is basically doing the following:

> For each value in 1, 2 and 3 do the following: while the current value is less than 5, print 'ha'

As you can read it, the value will start in 1 and, while 1 is lesser than 5, 'ha' will be printed. As the value is not updated, 1 will always be lesser than 5 so you will get infinite 'ha's

Your probably confused a `while` statement with an `if` statement

This makes more sense:

> For each value in 1, 2 and 3 do the following: if the current value is less than 5, print 'ha'

A tip for the starter: Try always to read/write your algorithms in your natural language and then try to program it in a computer language. Indeed programming languages are hard because they are evolving to a more human form and they need you to think more mathematically and more structured

Answer (score 2):

`for i in range(1, 3)` means it starts with the number `1`.

You're saying, with the number 1:

```
while 1 < 5:
    print('ha')
```

Which will go on forever, because one is less than five, and it will always be.

Thus the for-loop will never reach `2` and `3`, as it hasn't finished with `1` yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't modify `i` inside the `while` loop, so if the loop condition is true, it will always be true.  Perhaps you meant `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Because while defines a loop too. The code is building what's called a nested loop. Differently from the for loop, the while loop does not update the iterator variable (actually there's no iterator on the while loop, only a condition) and since the loop body does not change the condition, then i < 5 is always true and the while loop is infinite.

Maybe you wanted an if operation instead of a nested loop ?

```
for i in range (1,3):
    if i < 5:
        print ('ha')
```